# RawChip that returns Map

Tags: dart, flutter

I want to have RawChip that returns Map i.e. I want to display the label but when you click/tap it the real value that will be processed. Can we achieve this?

Normally standard RawChip like this (and this works)

```
final List<Widget> bannerChips = bannerBloc.bannerFilter.map<Widget>((String _text) {      
  return 
    Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
      child: RawChip(
        label: Text(_text),         
        selected: bannerBloc.selectedBanner == _text,
        onSelected: (bool isSelected) {
          setState(() {
            bannerBloc.selectedBanner = isSelected ? _text : '';
          });
        },
      ));
}).toList();
```

Now I want to return Map something like this

```
final List<Widget> bannerChips = bannerBloc.bannerFilter.map<Widget>((Map<String,dynamic> _map) {  
  return 
    Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
      child: RawChip(
        showCheckmark: false,
        label: Text(_map['label']),           
        selected: bannerBloc.selectedBanner == _map['label'],
        onSelected: (bool isSelected) {
          setState(() {
            bannerBloc.selectedBanner = isSelected ? _map['label'] : '';
          });
        },
      ));
}).toList();
```

But I cannot make it work. I got this error message

> type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'Map' of '_map'

What do I do wrong?

The bannerFilter would looks like this when I want it to be map

```
  List<Map<String, dynamic>> bannerFilter = [
    { 'label': 'All', 'value': 0 },
    { 'label': 'Shipped', 'value': 1 }
  ];
```

Comment: Everywhere you use `_map['label]` you're missing the closing quote, it should be `_map['label']`

Comment: @JordanDavies oh yes thank you but it is not the real problems actually just typo

Comment: Doesn't sound like `bannerBloc.bannerFilter` is actually `List<Map<String, dynamic>> bannerFilter = [
    { 'label': 'All', 'value': 0 },
    { 'label': 'Shipped', 'value': 1 }
  ];`.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer you are the man once again. stupid me.... Sometimes I just cannot understand the error message flutter throwing.

Comment: Glad to hear you could figure it out \o/

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer thanks...you could give answer so I can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message indicates that `bannerBloc.bannerFilter` is not

```
  List<Map<String, dynamic>> bannerFilter = [
    { 'label': 'All', 'value': 0 },
    { 'label': 'Shipped', 'value': 1 }
  ];
```

as you expect.

Comment: Thank you... once I changed to Map<String,String> all works. I forgotten how do i get into <String,dynamic> I saw somewhere and it says must be dynamic/Object.